# How often can a Riemann rearrangement give the same result?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

(From wikipedia) The Riemann series theorem (also called the Riemann rearrangement theorem), named after 19th-century German mathematician Bernhard Riemann, says that if an infinite series is conditionally convergent, then its terms can be arranged in a permutation so that the series converges to any given value, or even diverges.

Let $A=(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$
be a conditionally convergent series,
so that
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$
converges and
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|$
diverges.

Riemann's theorem says that,
for any real number $r$,
there is a permutation
$\pi_r$ of $\mathbb{N}$
such that
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{\pi_r(i)}$
converges to $r$.

My question is "Given $A$ and $r$,
how many permutations of $A$
 are there that give $r$?"

It seems clear to me that
there are at least $\aleph_0$
such permutations,
since you can go beyond $r$
as far as you want in as many places as you want,
and then do the same going down.

But, since there are
an uncountable number of permutations
of $\mathbb{N}$
(since, engaging in notation-abuse,
 $\aleph_0! \ge 2^{\aleph_0}$),
are there any real numbers $r$
for which there are an
uncountable number of permutations
whose rearranged sum converges to $r$?

I would also like to know 
what the answer is to the same question
about divergent rearrangements.

Comment: My feeling is that thinking in terms of cardinalities isn't going to give you a very interesting answer, simply because there aren't a lot of cardinalities it could be to start with. It would be interesting to find a more precise measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can produce continuum many.  For simplicity of exposition, assume initially that the terms are all different.

Take any rearrangement that gives sum $r$, where $r$ may be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Permute the first and second entries  if you feel like it, and then, if you feel like it, the $11$th and $12$th, and the $21$st and $22$nd, and so on forever.  The sum is unaffected.  We obtain  $2^{\aleph_0}$ permutations in this way.

If the terms are not all different, a small modification is needed. We say there is a *transition* at $n$ if $a_n\ne a_{n+1}$. Every tenth transition, do as in the case where the terms are all distinct.

**Remark:** For completeness, we explain why the sums are all equal to $r$. Most partial sums agree, except (in the simple case) possibly the first and second, the $11$th and the $12$th, and so on. But the terms go to $0$, so the partial sums converge to $r$.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the permutation of every _tenth_ entry is arbitrary; you only require that the terms you choose to switch out have the same sign?