# Number of permutations for a conditional convergence series

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations, rational-numbers, riemann-sum, conditional-convergence

I'm asking the next thing:

If we have a rational conditionally convergent series: $$\beta=\sum_{i=0}^\infty q_i \; \; \; ({q_i}\in\Bbb Q)$$
Then we know thanks to Riemann that it may be rearranged to converge to any value at all, but here's my question: ¿if there's a rearrangement $(q_{\sigma(n)})_{n}$, how can we know that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty q_{\sigma(i)}$ converges to $\beta$? (you can impose conditions on sigma if you want).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446975/how-often-can-a-riemann-rearrangement-give-the-same-result?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, I changed my question for this.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are looking for. In particular, are you familiar with the proof of Riemann rearrangement theorem? It is argued there how to construct a satisfactory permutation. How does that differ from what you are asking?

Comment: @AndrewZhang I'm asking how can we know if a permutation will be a specific number. I know the theorem, but the proof is based only in one permutation. I ask: If we have a permutation, how can we know if this sum will be a number that we want? Sorry for the unclear question.